# Pandas Data Frame Dollar Return Calculation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I am really struggling with an issue in python. I am working on calculating the dollar return from an equal weighted portfolio of stocks. I have the monthly returns for the following five stocks (SPY, DIS, XLK, BTC, and ARKK) and the portfolio, but I am running into problems on the last calculation.

**The following data frame looks like this**

- average column is just the row average of all stocks
  returns.)
- Dollar return is what I need to solve

I have average column such as :

| Average |
| --- |
| -0.038120 |
| -0.078641 |
| 0.102472 |
| -0.024291 |

and my expected output is as following :

| Average | Dolor_return |
| --- | --- |
| -0.038120 | .96188 |
| -0.078641 | .886237 |
| 0.102472 | .977051 |
| -0.024291 | .953318 |

- The mathematics formula for the dollar return column is as follows. Also, I need to perform theses calculations for all of the rows in the data frame.

  ```
  1*(1+(-0.038120)) = 0.96188
  0.96188*(1+(-.078641)) = 0.886237
  0.886237*(1+.102472) = 0.977051
  0.977051*(1+(-.024291)) = 0.953318
  ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have `dataframe` such as:

```
dictionary = {'average': [-0.038120,  -0.078641, 0.102472, -0.024291]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dictionary)
```

Then, you can create `function` to calculates your dolor return, such as following:

```
def calc(df):
    x = 1
    li = []
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if i == 0 :
            dolor_return = (x * 1) * (1 + (df['average'][i]))
            li.append(dolor_return)
        else:
            dolor_returns = (li[i - 1] * 1) * (1 + (df['average'][i]))
            li.append(dolor_returns)
    return li
```

It will return the valuse as a `list` format, and you can convert the `list` as `dataframe` format as follwing :

```
df['dolor_retunrs'] = calc(df)
```

The output would be :

```
Out[1]: 
    average  dolor_retunrs
0 -0.038120       0.961880
1 -0.078641       0.886237
2  0.102472       0.977051
3 -0.024291       0.953318
```